# How to add postfix url with proxy_pass nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, winginx

I am new to nginx server. I have want to send my request of

http://localhost:81/app/get/all

to

http://localhost:9000/abc/get/all

I have using location regex. But it not working can any one help me.

I have add server as:

```
 upstream dev {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
server {
        rewrite_log on;
        listen [::]:81;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   path;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location ~ ^/app/.+ {
        proxy_pass  http://dev;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify the location as a prefix location, you can use the `proxy_pass` directive to modify the URI:

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://dev/abc/;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Alternatively, you can rewrite the URI using the `break` modifier:

```
location ~ ^/app/. {
    rewrite ^/app(.*)$ /abc$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://dev;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.